# Secured API endpoints

Tags: api, security, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I’m building an API that returns a QR code.

The API endpoint should get the follwing:
email, client_id & client_secret.

My API should check the client id and secret, then encrypts the email(and more data) and then make a QR Code from the encrypted token.

How can I secure this API so an attacker won’t be able to send me a fake email?

I'm trying to understand how OAuth requests are secured against mitm attacks. When I read about it, it seems like my server needs to make an https request to the OAuth provider including this data.

**I’m having hard time to understand how an attacker won’t see the client id and secret (even if the request made through the consumer server).**

Hoping for help, 
Thanks!

Comment: The question is unclear... what is sent to the endpoint? the client_id and client_secret?

Comment: The endpoint should get an email, client_id and a client secret. over https - server to server.
The question is: Is it secured enough?

Comment: How can an attacker not see the client_secret if he is sending it in the request?

Comment: This is what I ask. How a website can send their client id and client secret to the OAuth providers without being attacked? So giving me a bad reputation on a question you clearly didn’t understood, it’s a bit rude and unfair. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You want to avoid that the client send the request to wrong oauth provider? Or you want to avoid a man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how OAuth requests are secured against mitm attacks. When I read about it, it seems like my server needs to make an https request to the OAuth provider including this data. So my question was - is it safe enough and an attacker can't sniff this request because its made through ssl and server-to-server communication.

Comment: You should update that to your question. Now it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how OAuth requests are secured against mitm attacks.

To protect against MITM attacks when using OAuth2 you must use TLS (https) connection.

> How can I secure this API so an attacker won’t be able to send me a fake email?

To avoid *fake email*, you need to verify the address, e.g. sending a mail with a *one-time code* that the user need to interact with. E.g. [OpenID Connect](http://For%20example,%20OpenID%20Connect%20already%20defines%20additional%20claims%20to%20inform%20the%20RP%20of%20the%20verification%20status%20of%20the%20phone_number%20and%20email%20claims.), an authentication standard based on OAuth2 has special *claim* to inform wether the email is verified or not.

> OpenID Connect already defines additional claims to inform the RP of the verification status of the phone_number and email claims.